# `mojo routes` just shows "/*whatever * whatever"

Tags: mojolicious

I have copied the exact example from [*Minimal Routes*](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing.pod#Minimal-route) into `myapp.pl`

```perl
# Application
package MyApp;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {
  my $self = shift;

  # Router
  my $r = $self->routes;

  # Route
  $r->get('/welcome')->to(controller => 'foo', action => 'welcome');
}

1;
```

When I run `mojo routes`, I get

```
/*whatever  *  whatever
```

When I run `mojo routes myapp.pl`, I get

```
/*whatever  *  whatever
```

How is `mojo routes` supposed to function, when I run `mojo --help | grep -i routes` it says,

```
routes    Show available routes
```

If I run `myapp.pl routes`, it shows nothing. How do I get a listing of the routes, as provided in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code copied is for a module. Mojo creates a startup script. This script is the argument required for the `routes` command. Generate a project with

```
mojo generate app MyApp
```

then checkout `script/my_app`, it contains

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                       

use strict;                                                                                               
use warnings;                                                                                             

use FindBin;                                                                                              
BEGIN { unshift @INC, "$FindBin::Bin/../lib" }                                                            
use Mojolicious::Commands;                                                                                

# Start command line interface for application                                                            
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('MyApp');
```

You'll see the code for the file you copied in `lib/MyApp.pm`. You'll want to run

Now you can run

```
script/my_app routes
/  GET
```

It will check the files in lib to generate the route listing.

---

*Thanks to Grinnz and CandyAngel on Freenode (IRC) in #mojo for providing the support to answer this.*